# Woocommerce + Stripe issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, fee

I need some info. I have a WordPress website using Hivepress theme + Woocommerce extension with Stripe integration. Everything is working as this:

1. user book the hotel and pay
2. we get the money and hold it
3. users release the payment by clicking on a button. The payments go directly from our stripe account to the hotel one.

I want to add a commission to it. It's actually easy from woocommerce so I can see everything in the cart 100$ hotel + 15% commission and I get the total amount to my stripe. The problem is that the payouts I mentioned before will contain also this commission (so the hotel is getting the total + my commission).

I can't split this amount and fees in my stripe.

[I should be able to see those 18$ in "Collected fee" in Stripe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBxPT.png)

Anyone one can help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Collected fees" will display amounts that have been collected as application fees: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-application_fee_amount

It sounds like the commissions are being included in the PaymentIntent `amount` instead of as a separate `application_fee_amount`. If WooCommerce manages the PaymentIntent creation, I recommend working with them to see if their Stripe integration supports the use of application fees.

Comment: Exactly looks like that! I have a developer helping me with that. I've contacted Stripe dev on the web chat and they also point me to Woocommerce due looks like some code is missing probably in Woocommerce or in the Stripe integration. Still waiting for an answer from Woocommerce help desk, forum, and community. The craziest is that I can't find anything similar on the web. That's why to explain myself I use the Airbnb example that is pretty similar to what I'm doing. Anyway thanks for the tip I really appreciate it!